# TCP client/server send/receive files

Tags: c, tcp, client-server

I am writing a TCP server/client program and want to send files from the server to the client. Here is my code which does not work sending the file. I use `recv()` and `send()` to send the files. Thanks in advance.

Client side:

```
char *location = "/home/kostas/Downloads/download.txt";
FILE *download = fopen( location, "w+" );
if( download == NULL )
{
    printf( "Error\n" );
    fflush( stdout );
}
int transfer = 0;
memset( buffer, 0, 1024 );
while( ( transfer = recv( connFd, buffer, 1024 , 0 ) > 0 ) )
{
    int write = fwrite( buffer, sizeof( char ), transfer, download );
    memset( buffer, 0, 1024 );
    if( ( transfer == 0 ) || ( transfer != 1024 ) )
    {
        break;
    }
}
memset( buffer, 0, 1024 );
if( read( connFd, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) ) < 0 )
{
    printf( "Read error\n" );
    fflush( stdout );
}
```

Server side :

```
//i get the filename by read/write
FILE *file = fopen( fileName, "r");
memset( buffer, 0, 1024 );
int i = 0;
while( ( i = fread( buffer, sizeof( char ), 1024, file ) ) < 0 )
{
    if( send( connFd, buffer, i, 0 ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "Error\n" );
        fflush( stdout );
    }
    memset( buffer, 0, 1024 );
}
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong? After that I intend to use posix threads to achieve the file transfer.

Comment: Check the receiving `while` loop again, you placed some parentheses wrong. Actually, you have the same problem with the read loop in the server. You might want to check e.g. [this operator precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: donte tell me i = fread... < 0. let me check it but i think that this is my mistake.

Comment: i did changed it but still it doesnt work :/

Comment: Well, does the client connect succeed?  Does the server accept() return?  Have you done any debuggging at all?

Comment: yes the client connect succeed as well as accept returned. Yes i did debugging. I also corrected the parethesis in the while loop. but still...

Comment: Get rid of the '|| ( transfer != 1024 )' condition.  Just because you ask recv() for 1024 bytes does not mean that is what you will get!  You may get less, and your recv() loop will drop out early.  Just go around until you get 0, indicating that the peer has closed the connection.

Answer (score 1):

```
while( ( transfer = recv( connFd, buffer, 1024 , 0 ) > 0 ) ) {
    int write = fwrite( buffer, sizeof( char ), transfer, download );
```

You are good up to here.

```
 memset( buffer, 0, 1024 );
```

Pointless. Remove.

```
 if( ( transfer == 0 ) || ( transfer != 1024 ) )
 {
     break;
 }
```

`transfer` (a) cannot be zero at this point, and (b) can be anything between 1 and 1024 here. There is no reason to stop if it isn't 1024. Remove this block.

```
memset( buffer, 0, 1024 );
```

Pointless. Remove.

```
if( read( connFd, buffer, sizeof( buffer ) ) < 0 )
{
    printf( "Read error\n" );
    fflush( stdout );
}
```

You need to store the `read()` result in a variable, and:

- test it for -1, which indicates a read error, which you should *print*, via `perror()` or `strerror()`
- test it for zero, which indicates end of stream
- otherwise use it as the read count in the following code, just as you have above.

But I don't know why you're reading anything at this point. The input is already exhausted or a read error has already occurred. Remove it.

```
memset( buffer, 0, 1024 );
```

Pointless. Remove.

```
int i = 0;
```

The initialization is pointless. Remove.

```
while( ( i = fread( buffer, sizeof( char ), 1024, file ) ) < 0 )
{
    if( send( connFd, buffer, i, 0 ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "Error\n" );
```

At this point, again, you should *print the error,* as mentioned above. Just printing 'Error' is useless. When it happens, you will immediately want to know what it was, and you will have to go back and modify the code to find out.

```
    memset( buffer, 0, 1024 );
```

Pointless. Remove.

Comment: 3 years later!! This was my first exercise for the network class!(I was in my second year of cs). I recall that I had fixed the mistakes because I got a good grade on that exercise! Thanks for answering though!